# Будет ли такое условие убрано компилятором?

Tags: c++, c

Интересует, как поведет себя компилятор в следующих случаях (уберет он условие или нет и при каком включенном уровне оптимизации)

1.1)

```
if (true) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

1.2)

```
if (true) {
    // какой-то код
} else {
    // какой-то код
}
```

2.1)

```
const bool isEnable = true;
if (isEnable) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

2.2)

```
const bool isEnable = true;
if (isEnable) {
    // какой-то код
} else {
    // какой-то код
}
```

3.1)

```
constexpr bool isEnable = true;
if (isEnable) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

3.2)

```
constexpr bool isEnable = true;
if (isEnable) {
    // какой-то код
} else {
    // какой-то код
}
```

Так же интересует, какие есть способы создания `#IFDEF`-а, который будет включать/выключать куски кода в зависимости от `true` или `false`, заданные на этапе компиляции.

Языки `C` и `C++`. Но на `С` вряд ли что-то такое можно придумать, а вот на плюсах новых стандартов может можно (до `C++14` включительно)

---

UPD. Под включать/выключать понимается, что из

```
if (true) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

получится

```
// какой-то код
```

А

```
if (false) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

будет выкинуто компилятором совсем

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду под "уберет он условие или нет"? Сделать так, чтобы компилятор вообще не видел и не проверял "какой-то код" через `if` невозможно - только через `if constexpr`. А что касается исключения "лишнего" кода после проверки, то это любой уважающий себя компилятор сделает. Никакого общего понятия "уровня оптимизации" не существует.

Comment: Ну к примеру, он увидит, что `if` всегда истина и поэтому оставит уже на компиляции от него только истинную ветвь. Такое наверняка происходит с флагами типа `-O3`, а вот происходит ли без оптимизации такой, я не знаю

Comment: На такой вопрос трудно отвечать, ибо не ясно какую цель он преследует и какое это вообще имеет значение. Оставит/ не оставит - какая разница. А увидите, что оставляет - поднимете уровень оптимизации.

Comment: Хотелось включать-выключать кусок кода на этапе компиляции с помощью булевой константы. Пока думал, как такое можно сделать, задумался о поведении компилятора в таких случаях

Comment: По-прежнему не понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "включать-выключать". Сделать так, чтобы компилятор вообще не видел и не проверял выключенный код? И в чем проблема с обычным `#define ON 1` и затем `#if ON ... #endif`?

Comment: Вас какой-то *конкретный* компайлер интересует или вообще все...?

Comment: Вопрос обновил. Компилятор - желательно все, но ясное дело, что все не охватить

Comment: @AnT, ну, к примеру, про `#if ...` я до текущего момента не знал, только про `#IFDEF`, `#IFNDEF`, так что `#if` вполне подходит как ответ

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв: В общем случае компилятор ограничен только правилом as if. То есть он имеет право выкинуть что угодно, лишь бы на экран и в файлы вывелось то же самое. И добавить что угодно. А также имеет право и не выкидывать и не добавлять. Никаких «обязательств» по оптимизации у компилятора нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С++17 будет `if constexpr`:

```
constexpr auto cond = ...;
if constexpr (cond) {
    // код
    return 200;
} else if (expr) {
    // код
    return "100";
} else {
    // код
    return false;
}
```

А пока ничего такого нет, только `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Опять же, если в выражении compile-time константа, то компилятор соптимизирует и без `if constexpr`. Последний служит скорее для исключения кусков, которые просто не смогут скомпилироваться и обычно используется в обобщённом коде. Так что в данном вопросе он лишний, нормальному компилятору хватит `if`